# if control on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I need to insert an "if" control in my wordpress code because I want that this checkbox appears only with specific user. But I receive always an error.

```
<?php if ( !current_user_can('edit_users') ) {
    <?php $featured_checked = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_elist_featured', true ) && 'on' == get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_elist_featured', true ) ? ' checked="checked"' : ''; ?><label for="_elist_featured" class="selectit"><input name="_elist_featured" type="checkbox" id="_elist_featured" <?php echo esc_html( $featured_checked ); ?>><?php esc_html_e( 'This listing is featured.' ); ?></label></div> 

    } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to properly open and close the PHP tags surrounding your `IF` statement and closing curly brace. Your current code is missing `?>` at the end of the first line and `<?php` at the beginning of the last

Incorrect:

```
<?php if ( !current_user_can('edit_users') ) {
<-- your HTML and PHP -->
} ?>
```

Correct:

```
<?php if ( !current_user_can('edit_users') ) { ?>
<-- your HTML and PHP -->
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using additional `<?php` tags in your code.

FYI- try to use a good editor to fix these kinda bugs

```
<?php if ( !current_user_can('edit_users') ) {
    $featured_checked = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_elist_featured', true ) && 'on' == get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_elist_featured', true ) ? ' checked="checked"' : ''; 
?>
<label for="_elist_featured" class="selectit">
<input name="_elist_featured" type="checkbox" id="_elist_featured" <?php echo esc_html( $featured_checked ); ?>>
<?php esc_html_e( 'This listing is featured.' ); ?>
</label>
</div>
```